# Service property overriden

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reading [angular docs about services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), I had an impression that when injecting service, a new javascript object like instance is created and modifying one instance won't affect others. Seems I have got it wrong. 
See [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lvDI7Xl33HouOCANroUr?p=preview). I would expect that when pressing on `Alert Foo contrller name` I would see `foo/getFoo` not `bar/getFoo`.

Explanation why it works like this and possible workaround would be appreciated.

I want to rewrite plain javascript object into angularjs service. This is a restApi service which has GET, POST etc. methods, but the way it is implemented right now is that the Controller part of this service is set outside of it in factory and for all the REST methods, only the method name and parameters are passed. I'd like to keep this approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is exactly what is happening. see this line:

```
restApiService.setControllerName(...);
```

Is called in both services: `fooController` and `barController` (Which are terrible names for services). Because `restApiService` is instantiated **once** you are essentially mutating the same `restApiService` twice when the services are instantiated causing the undesired behavior.

Here's an example of a better defined service:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.service('restApiService', function() {
  var that = this;

  this.alertControllerName = function(controllerName) {
    alert(controllerName);
  }
});

app.factory('fooController', function(restApiService) {
  var controllerName = 'foo';
  return {
    alertControllerName: function() {
      restApiService.alertControllerName(controllerName);
    }
  }
});

app.factory('barController', function(restApiService) {
  var controllerName = 'bar';
  return {
    alertControllerName: function() {
      restApiService.alertControllerName(controllerName);
    }
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, fooController, barController) {
  
  $scope.alertFoo = fooController.alertControllerName;
  $scope.alertBar = barController.alertControllerName;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="alertFoo()">Alert Foo controller name</button>
    <button ng-click="alertBar()">Alert Bar controller name</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, ok. Those are just made up names I did for plunker, but you haven't got my point about desired result. I'd like to set the `controllerName` once so that I don't have to pass for every request. E.g. `restApi` `post` method's signature is `function (callback, methodName, data)` and inside I would append `controllerName` to `methodName`

Comment: Is this for analytics?

Comment: No. I hope to avoid rewriting lot of code. I updated plunker to better show expected result.

Comment: As I said, in current implementation, the controllerName is set only once in each factory initialization. I have large list of factories which represent specific controller. There, the controller is set once and in `GET, POST, PUT` etc. methods controllerName is not passed, only method's name, because controllerName has already been set! If I can't make it work similar like this, I'll have to go through every factory's method and add controller's name to metho's name.

Comment: You can't that's exactly what I'm trying to tell you mate. angular factories and services are **singletons** therefore when you `setControllerName` the second time you overwrite your previous controller name.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding AngularJS Factory, Service and Provider**

All of these are used to share reusable singleton objects. It helps to share reusable code across your app/various components/modules.

> - **Lazily instantiated** – Angular only instantiates a service/factory when an application component depends on it.
> - **Singletons** – Each component
>     dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
>     generated by the service factory.
>
> [-- AngularJS Developer Guide - Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)